# implement user role based on role value in mysql database in node express

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, express

I am facing a problem which I want to redirect the user after logging to screen based on his role stored in database,

So I am working on app using react native and my backend server is node express and my database is MySQL.
I have implemented login and it is working perfectly and in my app I have three dashboard screens one for admin and one for student and one for lecturer and I want to redirect the user login based on his role that has been stored in database in table users:
My database table structure:

```
----------------------------
id : int 
----------------------------
username:  string 
----------------------------
password: string 
----------------------------
role: string 
----------------------------
```

and below is my login function when login button pressed:

```
 login = () => {
  
    fetch('http://myip:3000/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
      
        if (res.success === true) {
          var role = AsyncStorage.getItem(role, res.user);

          if (role == 'admin') {

            AsyncStorage.setItem('admin', res.user);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminD')
          } else if (role == 'lecturer') {

            AsyncStorage.setItem('lecturer', res.user);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('lecturerD')
          } else if (role == 'student') {

            AsyncStorage.setItem('student', res.user);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('studentD')
          }

        }
        else {

          alert(res.message);
        }
      })
      .done()
```

and here the backend server code that handle this request:

```
 router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  //res.send({ message: req.body.username });
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var role = '';
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password =?",
    [username, password], function (err, row, field) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'couldnt connect to db lol' });
      } else if (username === '') {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Username required' });
      } else if (password === '') {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'password required' });
      } else if (row.length > 0) {
        connection.query("SELECT role FROM users WHERE username=? ", [username], function (err, row, field) {
          if (row[0].role === 'admin') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'admin': row[0].username });
          } else if (row[0].role === 'student') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'user': row[0].username });
            console.log(row[0].username)
          } else if (row[0].role === 'lecturer') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'lecturer': row[0].username });
          }
        });

      } else {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'user not found' });
      }
    });
});
```

// Side note:  there is no password hashing decryption because this only a demo.

I may have many simple mistakes but I am beginner to react native with express server requests,
I hope someone can lead me to a solutions.

Thank in advanced

Comment: why not just send back users role in the response ? or better yet, send back a key that lets the server manage what requests are allowed or not based on role.. This seems to offer the client control over its role..

Comment: @Pogrindis can i have example for how to done this please

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you for all I have manage to solve this problem and the code will look like this**

in the server side the cod will look like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  //res.send({ message: req.body.username });
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var role = '';
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password =?",
    [username, password], function (err, row, field) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'couldnt connect to db lol' });
      } else if (username === '') {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Username required' });
      } else if (password === '') {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'password required' });
      } else if (row.length > 0) {
        connection.query("SELECT role FROM users WHERE username=? ", [username], function (err, row, field) {
          if (row[0].role == 'admin') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'role': row[0].role, 'user': row[0].username });
          } else if (row[0].role == 'student') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'role': row[0].role, 'user': row[0].username });
            console.log(row[0].role)
          } else if (row[0].role == 'lecturer') {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'role': row[0].role, 'user': row[0].username });
          }
        });



        //  res.send({ 'success': true, 'user': row[0].username });
      } else {
        res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'user not found' });
      }
    });
});
```

and the the frontend the login function will look like this:

```
 login = () => {
  
    fetch('http://myip:3000/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        // alert(res.message);
        if (res.success === true && res.role === 'admin') {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminD')
        } else if (res.success === true && res.role === 'student') {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('studentD')
        } else if (res.success === true && res.role === 'lecturer') {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('lecturerD')
        }
        else {

          alert(res.message);
        }
      })
      .done()
  
  }
}
```

I hope this save hours of pain for someone :)